# Loading big amounts of html tags from text field from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, string

I wonder which method will be more efficient. I have around three hundred thousand DIV tags, which looks like this:

```
<div class="s" style="top:200px;left:100px;margin:0 2px 0 2px;">
here_comes_200chars_of_text</div>
```

Every single tag has different position and margin, that's why i can't put styles in css.

I want to put whole html code into a database, and load it from there when user needs it, and there comes my question. Is it better to store html like shown above, or to make it shorter with some php code to look like this :

```
<d c="s" s="t:200;l:100;m:0 2 0 2;">here_comes_200chars_of_text</d>
```

,upload it into database and recreate normal appearance when read?

It saves 20 chars per DIV. That makes ~6 million chars saved. That's why I'm asking.

I hope you get what I mean.
Best regards.

EDIT:

Typical use of web app:

User is creating large group of html objects, each representing some kind of element on the map. There are around 200 users overall, each has his own map with objects, and at one time web app won't be used by more than 20-30 users. They store data in each element of the map, between DIV tags. They can dynamically move, change margin of the separate DIVs and change content in DIVs. After editing the map, users will be able to save their work in database. That's why I wonder how to save those DIVs, which are created and modified by user.

I hope it clears my problem a little:)

Comment: You should store top, left, margin properties, don't store text or varchar when you can store numbers. You can have a table which store margin, with 4 columns (top, left, right, bottom), only numbers. And if you have 300 000 div to show, you maybe better use canvas for better performances.

Comment: Isn't the whole lot coming it less than 100MB? Why is this a problem anyway? The whole table will likely be in RAM. Despite that, Javi's answer is pretty sane - I'd avoid storing HTML in the DB unless there is no better way. If you later decided to use transforms instead of top/left for instance, you could easily change it if the styling isn't in the DB. Or, if you wanted to ship it as JSON then build the HTML in JS you could.

Comment: I know that we're talking about MBs of data, rather than GBs, however I believe that there would be a difference if user downloads 80MB in place of 100MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to create a table like this, I think is the more efficient way (similar to Vincent Decaux comment):

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`divs` (
  `text` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `top` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  `left` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  `margin-top` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  `margin-bottom` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  `margin-left` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  `margin-right` SMALLINT NOT NULL
);
```

This aproach uses 4 bytes x 6 fields = 24 bytes for the style, 16 bytes less than your approach supposing that you are storing the text as ASCII. If you use another charset the saving will be bigger.

Comment: However I have to load like 300 000 records from database for each user. Will it be more efficient than storing html in text field? And what about PRIMARY_KEY of that table - I would need another column with INT(6), which makes +1 field x 6 bytes, so overall only 10 bytes less than what I introduced.

Comment: You don't require a primary key - it depends on what type of queries you run. Also, you might be able to use unsigned TINYINTS (only 1 byte) if you don't need to values higher than 255. If you did need a primary key you could use a unsigned MEDIUMINT (max value = 16,777,215). (Also, SMALLINT are only 2 bytes in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: But how can I find div which user modified and update the row in database, if I dont have primary key and records in database are not unique? BTW - your approahc with TINYINTS will work for my margins values. Thank you.

Comment: you need some primary key, composite or not; then maybe you can use typical version column(INT) and check row versions in database and user

Comment: @WojciechHolysz If you need a primary key here you would need it in any solution. In relation to the unique rows, what do you need?

Answer (score 0):

If disk space saved is high priority you should **zip** the text and save it as **BLOB**. It saves bandwidth when connecting the database. If this is a good approach heavily depends on the scenario, maybe you can explain the usage in more detail? Eg. how many users, how often you modify the content etc.

**EDIT**
so if there is just 300,000 records and each is storable in 256 bytes you need 75m of memory approx plus per object metadata. maybe the database is not needed at all. how do you identify DIVs to be modified? still not much information about object usage. If you gonna modify data often use *Javi's solution* for storing and send data packed to the client where javascript will unpack and create HTML objects in place.

Comment: I added an edit in the post, look at it if u could. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I became misunderstood - each user will generate 300 000 rows, which makes 300 000 x 200 = 60 000 000 rows in one table, not overall 300 000 rows. Sadly.

Comment: alright so you need database :) no big deal, i would use mentioned Javi's table with customizations from other coments and focus on the communication between server and client, definitely the best way for large amount of data is the compression; try to pack all html being sent to one client and try to pack some JSON representation or parameters for your javascript method creating DOM objects; if not big difference just pick one you like the most ...

Comment: Well, then I will try yours and Javi's approach then:) I will use AJAX to modify rows immidiatelly after editing, so only page loading will take some time, not whole process including saving the data. Also, as you mentioned, JSON will come handy. Thanks for the support!